# type error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def converter():
    print ("Welcome to Andy's decimal to binary converter!")
    x = raw_input("Enter an integer or enter 'exit' to exit program:")

    if x=="exit":
        print "Goodbye"
        exit()

    string = ""

    while x!=0:
        remainder =x%2
        string =string+str(remainder) #giving error here and dont know why!
        x =x/2
    y =string
    binary =y[::-1]
    print "The integer in binary is: ",binary

    again =raw_input("Would you like to enter another integer? Enter yes or no: ")


    if again=="no":
        print "Goodbye"
        exit()
    elif again=="yes":
        return converter()
    else:
        print "Enter either 'yes' or 'no'"

print converter()
```

Comment: Is this all your code? What is the line that is causing the error?

Comment: It's conceivable that `x%2` could be doing it if `x` were non-numeric. If it's a string (and, given `raw_input`, it *will* be a string), then we'd be treating it as a format string

Comment: Your error is here: `remainder =x%2`.  `x` is a string and you are trying to treat it as an integer.  Before your while-loop make `x` an integer.  `x = int(x)`.

Comment: ...regardless of whether we were able to figure out the problem, though, this isn't a good question as currently written. Please follow the suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and most particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: so you should do `remainder = int(x) % 2`

Comment: @StamKaly, that's not sufficient -- there are other math operations done on `x` below.

Comment: right, so he should immediately convert x to an integer

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that it you are trying to do math on a string.

```
remainder = x%2
```

This is being seen as `"123" % (2)`, and since the string doesn't contain a valid character to replace you get that error.

To fix this I would recommend you convert the input to an integer after checking if the value is "exit". See:

```
if x=="exit":
    print "Goodbye"
    exit()
else:
  try: 
    x = int(x)
  except:
    print "%s is not a number!" % (x)
    return converter()
```

Here we use a try and except statement to handle if their input is not a number.